# Split tensorflow dataset based on condition

Tags: python, tensorflow, split, dataset

I want to split a `tf.data.Dataset` into two subdatasets based on a condition.

I have a list of values. If the row is present in the list of values then put it in the first subdataset, else put it in the second subdataset (my problem is quite more complex but this is the basic idea).

I know that I could do something along those lines:

```py
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.constant([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]))
to_keep_in_ds1 = tf.constant([1, 4, 8])
ds1 = ds.filter(lambda x: tf.math.count_nonzero(tf.equal(x, to_keep_in_ds1)) > 0)
ds2 = ds.filter(lambda x: tf.math.count_nonzero(tf.equal(x, to_keep_in_ds1)) == 0)
print("ds: ", list(ds.take(10).as_numpy_iterator()))
print("ds1:", list(ds1.take(10).as_numpy_iterator()))
print("ds2:", list(ds2.take(10).as_numpy_iterator()))
# ds:  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
# ds1: [1, 4, 8]
# ds2: [0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9]
```

However, I would like to avoid to filter the dataset twice as it is completely unnecessary (with this code, I will check that `x` is in `to_keep_in_ds1` twice even if once should be enough).

Ideally, I would like a method like:

```py
ds1, ds2 = ds.split_on_condition(lambda x: tf.math.count_nonzero(tf.equal(x, values_in_ds1)) > 0)
```

Comment: Have you tried filtering your data before feeding it to `tf.data.Dataset`?

Comment: The data I want to use won't fit in memory, and I need to be able to dynamically generate `to_keep_in_ds1`, so the only way to get what I want is to use the lazy `tf.data.Dataset` implementation (tensorflow reads the data from disk and apply incrementally the transformations only for the data that is needed)

Comment: How do you plan to use `ds1` and `ds2`?

Comment: @AloneTogether as train and test datasets (I can't just randomly split the dataset as I have some correlated records that I want to be either fully in the training set or fully in the testing set)

Comment: I do think there are other ways to solve this but I doubt you will get any significant performance gains